# signing up Codewars Java exercise 2

Tags: java, string, format, return

I've just tried to sign up and am currently on exercise two trying to figure it out. Here it the code.

```
public class Person {
    String name;

    public Person(String personName) {
        name = personName;
    }

    public String greet(String yourName) {
        return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", name, yourName);
    }
}
```

These are the changes I made that seemed to make sense at the time, but I'm still going through it to find what works

```
public class Person {
    String name;

    public Person(String personName) 
    {
        name = "John";
    }

    public String greet(String "Tommy");
    {
        return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", name, yourName);
    }
}
```

If I were to paste this into Eclipse and run it from there is it cheating?

I hope this was clear enough and if there are any ways I can improve this post or make anything clearer please let me know :) thanks!

Comment: Copy/paste and not understanding is cheating. There are loads of errors in the code, I recommend that you read basics of Java. I could answer you with corrections but, not sure how is that going to help you unless you start with the basics of Java.

Comment: This question is not about programming. OP participated in a coding game in another website and inquires about the rules of the game in that other website

Comment: I think your right, Im really really rusty on stuff and probably best off focusing on the basics thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

you just need to swap name and yourName in String.format() function, see the below code

```
return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", yourName, name);
```

```
public class Person {

  String name;

    public Person(String personName) {
      name = personName;
   }

    public String greet(String yourName) {
      return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", yourName, name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction and comments in the code below. You will understand everything if you do study some basics of the language otherwise it is going to be fun.

```
public class Person {
    String name;

    //This is a constructor and invoked during creation of object
    public Person(String personName) 
    {
            //makes no sense to pass personName to construct but, not use it
            //name = "John";
            name = personName; 
    }

    //A method signature does not end with semi-colon
    //You cannot pass string literal in function as argument, "Tommy" incorrect arg
    //public String greet(String "Tommy");
    public String greet(String greeting)
    {
            //not sure where you come up with yourName but, i replaced with greeting arg
            return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", name, greeting);
    }

    //add main to show you how this works, when run execution enters main first
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //an object of Person class is created passing "John" to its constructor      
        Person p  = new Person("John"); 

        //p.greet() invokes the greet method of Person object
        System.out.println(p.greet("Oops!")); 
    }
}
```